# React.ts Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, zustand

I am trying to fetch a new set of users every time I press the button and update existing users. But when I am even entering the page, it gives me `Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.` error. I tried a bunch of stuff, but nothing really worked. this is my code.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Server } from "../../server/auth";
import { useAppStore } from "../../zustand/store";
import UserCard from "./userCard";

export default function AdminPanel() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<Common.User[]>([]);
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
  const { authData, setAuthData } = useAppStore();
  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const data = await Server.fetchUsers(offset, authData?.token);
    setUsers((state) => state.concat(data));
    setOffset(users.length);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);
  return (
    <section className="ap-bg bgw">
      <div className="users d-grid">
        {users.map((user, index) => UserCard(user, `u-${index}`))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => fetchUsers()}>Fetch 10 more users</button>
    </section>
  );
}
```

In here I have [users, setUsers], which is a state of current users, [offset, setOffset] this is the user I will fetch from(i.e. every time instead of fetching 10 users, then 20, then 30 etc., I am fetching 10 users from 0 to 10, then 10 users from 10 to 20 and add them to existing ones etc.), and authData, setAuthData is my zustand store. The code seems correct, and yet I get an error. What is the error here and how can I fix it?

Comment: The error "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render" occurs when we conditionally call a hook or return early before all hooks have run.

To solve the error, move all hooks at the top level of the function component and don't use hooks inside conditions.

Comment: Could you also provide the code to UserCard? The error could be there too!

Comment: @YHR, of course, here it is: https://pastebin.com/CK2XqeDt

Comment: Could you comment out this component (Admin Panel) in your code? This would confirm the error is in this component (Admin Panel)!

Comment: @YHR, yes, the error is indeed in Admin Panel, moreover, if I comment out the setUsers((state) => state.concat(data));, it works without any errors

Answer (score 3):

My problem was deeper, inside UserCard, because each of it had an additional state, so when I added users, it added states. solved now, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
<section className="ap-bg bgw">
  <div className="users d-grid">
    {users.map((user, index) =>  (
       <UserCard user={user} id={`u-${index}`} />
    ))}
  </div>
  <button onClick={() => fetchUsers()}>Fetch 10 more users</button>
</section>
```

here instead of this => {users.map((user, index) => UserCard(user, `u-${index}`))}

use like JSX component call like above, It will also solve the issue.